# React - fade in div, pause and fade out div

Tags: css, reactjs, fadein, fadeout

In my React app, I am trying to fade a div in, wait a bit, and fade it back out.  Everything is working great except the fade out.
My SCSS looks like this:

```
$orange-color: #DD7C15;
$white-color: #FFFFFF;
$black-color: #222222;

.App {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}

.message-banner {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 100000;
  width: 100vw;
  color: $orange-color;
  font-size: 4em;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: $white-color;
  border: 2px solid $black-color;
  opacity: 0.9;
  animation: fadeIn 2s ease-in;

  &.hide {
    opacity: 0;
    animation: fadeOut 2s ease-out;
  }
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0.9;
  }
}

@keyframes fadeOut {
  0% {
    opacity: 0.9;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

And my relevant React code:

```
const showBanner = () => {
    setMessageBannerText("My sweet awesome banner!!");
    setTimeout(() => {
      setMessageBannerText("");
    }, 3000);
  };

  const bannerClasses =
    messageBannerText === "" ? "message-banner hide" : "message-banner";
```

I've created a sandbox showing what I am talking about.
https://codesandbox.io/s/brave-grass-q1y6j

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hey I have edited your sandbox to achieve the result you desire:-

[image: Edit vigilant-water-x135f]

Changes:-

1) Added `show` and `hide` classes.

2) Introduced a boolean state for transition rather than depending on text because your `message-banner` div doesn't have its own height or width. We will simply let the text stay but hide the div away from the user.

3) Instead of `animation`, used `transition` since you're simply toggling between two states and you want to stick with those for rest of your application. With animation, you will have to do some more tricks for them to stick. Plus `animation` is useful for more complex scenario.

Answer (score 3):

**Issue :**

The animation is working fine but you are removing the content `setMessageBannerText("");` while the animation, so it's not visible

---

**Solution :**

So instead of making content blank, you should maintain the state for animation

**1) Solution :**

```
const steps = {
  0: "", // <--- blank coz message-banner has animation itself
  1: "message-banner",
  2: "message-banner hide"
};

export default function App() {
  const messageBannerText = "My sweet awesome banner!!";
  const [animationStep, setAnimationStep] = useState(0);

  const showBanner = () => {
    setAnimationStep(1);
    setTimeout(() => {
      // setMessageBannerText(""); // <---- issue
      setAnimationStep(2);
    }, 3000);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      <button onClick={showBanner}>Show Banner</button>
      <MessageBanner text={messageBannerText} classes={steps[animationStep]} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

WORKING DEMO :

[image: Edit #SO-animate-issue2]

---

**2) Solution :** ( with css changes, but you still need to follow above changes )

```
.message-banner {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 100000;
  width: 100vw;
  color: $orange-color;
  font-size: 4em;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: $white-color;
  border: 2px solid $black-color;
  opacity: 0;

  &.animate {
    opacity: 0;
    animation: fadeInOut 5s ease-out;
  }
}

// single animation for fade in and fade out
@keyframes fadeInOut {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  30% {
    opacity: 0.9;
  }
  70% {
    opacity: 0.9;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```
  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);

  const showBanner = () => {
    if (!show) { // <--- just for safe side, if animation is going on, then ignore state change
      setShow(true);
      setTimeout(() => {
        setShow(false);
      }, 5000);
    }
  };

  const bannerClasses = show ? "message-banner animate" : "message-banner";
```

WORKING DEMO :

[image: Edit #SO-animate-issue]